# How to bulkify a trigger that is having a method to call a future method?

Tags: trigger, callout, bulkification

I am having a trigger on Case object. The objective of the trigger is to create a Service Notification record in SAP. As the best practices suggest that we need to bulkify the trigger to avoid governor limit issues, I too followed it. But my issue is what would happen to the webservice callouts while we mass load data into the case object.

**Trigger code:**

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert,after update) {
    List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id> ();
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            for(Case c: Trigger.New) {
                caseIds.add(c.Id);
            }
            SAPServices.CreateServiceNotification(caseIds);
        }
    }
}
```

SAPServices is a utility class which is having a future method CreateServiceNotification that makes a webservice callout to SAP. Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your trigger is bulkified, so would make one call to the @future method for every 200 records that are loaded. As long as your call-out method can handle lists, and it appears that it can based on the way the way you've written the code to make the call to it, it would appear that you should be fine. The only potential issue would be any limits associated with the @future method itself and how many you can have in the queue at any given time.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Is there a way or a method to find out how many callouts have been made already and how many of them are in queue to just to prevent the future method by making further callouts to the webservice?

Comment: Yes, there's the `getLimitCallouts()` method to see how many are available for one. Then there's `getFutureCalls()` and also `getLimitFutureCalls()` in terms of what's what's been called, but not necessarily completed and what's available to be called. See the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm%23apex_methods_system_limits?search_text=portal%20user) for more.

Comment: if you are going to break the futurecalls limit, look into Salesforce Queueable classes..

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Simon: will look into Queueable classes if the future calls hit governor limits.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @SimonLawrence. Queueable classes have many advantages. They can be very easily tracked and immediately have an Id upon creation. Ultimately, they're the way to go and will be the standard of the future (no pun intended).

Comment: Be careful doing async work from triggers,. if another developer wants to do DML on your object from an async context this will cause in most cases platform exceptions that prevent async work being started from another async context (there are some exceptions but they depend on you issuing only one more async job, depends on trigger chunking or being in the finish phase of a batch job). There is really no way round this other than to change the architecture of your solution to use scheduled worked. That said if your happy this use case won't manifest in your case thats fine.